# How to trigger event in NodeJs based on database time values?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, triggers

I need to perform some actions in my app based on user's input. For e.g. if user selects 17:00-18:00, the timeframe is updated in the MySQL db and something should happen in that specific time.

Could someone tell me how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cron jobs for it.

For example, if you need to do some actions based on time value in your DB, you can write some code, that gets the current date and selects from MySQL all raws if your current date is between the date range of that raw and process them.

Then just make some cronjob that calls your code every minute, or an hour or whatever you need.

You can use [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) package for that.

Here is an example:

```
const { CronJob } = require('cron');

// example cron job
const yourFunction = require('./yourFile.js');

// setting cron for example cronJob
const cron = new CronJob('0 * * * * *', yourFunction, null, true);

cron.start();
```

Or you can use Linux's crontab, you can read about how to use it [here](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux).

Configure frequency of cron with cron scheduler, you can play with it [here](https://crontab.guru/).